# Error al debuggear en Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, vscode, depuración

Estoy tratando de codear en C++. Tengo problemas con la configuración del Debugger para Visual Studio Code. Me salta este problema:

> The preLaunchTask 'C/C++: gcc.exe build active file' terminated with exit code -1

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: visual studio? o visual studio code? son dos mundos muy diferentes...

Comment: Visual Studio Code* lo tipee mal en el titulo, pero de igual forma ahi aparece en la captura :)

Comment: pusiste mal el tag tambien.. y la captura no la veo.. es dificil para algunos ver imagenes.. en lo posible los errores deben ir como texto...

Comment: Sisi, aparece en la captura, no se por que no llegas a verlo

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

Comment: No son errores en la terminal, es una ventana, deberia escribir todo lo de la ventana a texto sin incluir ninguna captura?

Comment: Idealmente, utiliza un IDE completo o la línea de comandos. Si insistes con VS Code necesitamos más información ¿Qué compilador quieres utilizar? ¿Cuáles son las configuraciones del Workspace (los archivos que se encuentran en la carpeta `.vscode`)?

Comment: Quizás sería útil que compartieras tus archivos launch.json y, sobre todo, tasks.json.